# Embed OpenSceneGraph in a Windows form

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, openscenegraph

I'm new to OpenSceneGraph and I'm trying to test it with Visual Studio 2010.

In OpenSceneGraph examples models are usually shown with `osgViewer::Viewer`, fullscreen. I need to embed such viewer (or anything else that can display a model) inside a WinForms form, deciding the space it can take. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this is addressed in the OSG FAQ: http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/support/faq#HowdoIembedanOSGviewerina.NETcontrol